# Localized resources in ios static library

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, bundle, static-libraries

I followed this [Tutorial](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/ios-library-with-resources/) to use resources in my ios static library.
Now, I can use images, xib files, plist files... into my static library but I can't use localized resources..

In my bundle resources I can see all (for example) images into correct folders (es: english image into en.lproj folder)
But .. when I load the image, I see always the english image also when my language device is different from english.

I have same problem about localized strings: always I see only english localized strings.

* EDIT ****

I could not find a better solution for this problem ..
I was in a hurry to fix this so I duvuto apply this method to solve the problem with the localized images:

```
 + (NSString*) getLocalizedPathImageWithImageName:(NSString*) aImageName
    {
        NSString *currentDeviceLanguage = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *resourceBundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:BUNDLE_RESOURCESNAME ofType:@"bundle"];
        NSString *completeLocalizedImageName = [aImageName stringByAppendingFormat:@"_%@",currentDeviceLanguage];
        NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:resourceBundlePath] pathForResource:completeLocalizedImageName ofType:USERBUTTON_PNG_FILEEXTENSION];
        if (imagePath == nil) {
            completeLocalizedImageName = [aImageName stringByAppendingFormat:@"_%@",DEFAULT_LANGUAGE];
            imagePath = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:resourceBundlePath] pathForResource:completeLocalizedImageName ofType:USERBUTTON_PNG_FILEEXTENSION];
        }
        return imagePath;
    }
```

a better solution is welcome

Comment: How are you loading localized strings? `NSLocalizedString()` only looks in the main bundle, so if your library's strings are in a different bundle you'll need `NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle()`.

Comment: Yes, I use NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle() but my principal problem is about localized images

Comment: did you find a solution for that?
got same issue...

Comment: @mindbomb: I Added a possible solution about localized images..I think this isn't the better solution.. I was in a hurry and I thought I'd do it this way ..  I hope this can help

Comment: I found a different "hack" solution:

`NSString *localeDir = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.lproj",[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"] objectAtIndex:0]];`

`NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:TOPICS_FILE_TYPE inDirectory:localeDir]; `